# Ficheiro ".js" gerado pelo Gulp retorna o erro "require is not defined"

Tags: javascript, gulpjs

Instalei o Gulp para concatenar e minificar os meus ficheiros `.js`, porém o seguinte erro ocorre no browser quando vou testar a aplicação:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
```

Tenho o `gulpfile.js` da seguinte forma:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpif = require('gulp-if');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var uglifycss = require('gulp-uglifycss');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src([
        'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        'node_modules/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.js',
        'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js',
        'node_modules/amcharts3/amcharts/amcharts.js',
        'node_modules/amcharts3/amcharts/serial.js',
        'node_modules/amcharts3/amcharts/pie.js',
        'src/Havas/AdminBundle/Resources/public/js/chart.js',
        'src/Havas/AdminBundle/Resources/public/js/map.js',
        'src/Havas/AdminBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js',
        'src/Havas/AdminBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2/jquery-jvectormap-us-aea-en.js',
        'src/Havas/AdminBundle/Resources/public/js/main.js'
    ])
    .pipe(concat('javascript.js'))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('web/js'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['js']);
```

Como corrigir esse erro? O que fiz errado?

Comment: _"o seguinte erro ocorre no browser"_, o `require` é ambiente Node.js.

Comment: @Sergio sim esse erro aparece na console do browser e é no javascript concatenado e minificado pelo Gulp. Eu entendo que `require` é ambiente NodeJs, mas isso é o output do Gulp, não entendo o que fiz de errado.

Comment: @Sergio não encontrei a solução, entretanto passei a utilizar o bower no projeto com Gulp, resultou e já não retorna nenhum erro no browser.